# Multiple ssh keys on server

Tags: ssh

One one machine (client), I want to ssh to another machine (server) by `ssh server`.

On both machines in `~/.ssh`, I have two RSA keys:

```
id_rsa
id_rsa.pub
id_rsa_other
id_rsa_other.pub
```

id_rsa_other are consistent between the two machines, since the files on client were scp'ed to server.

The id_rsa files are for other connections, and I don't expect them to work with each other.

Should I expect this to just work out of the box?  When I try `ssh server`, it checks keys but fails to authenticate and falls back to prompting for a password.

I tried adding

```
Host server
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_other
   Hostname <actual server name>
   User <actual user name on server>
```

to `~/.ssh/config` on client, but this did not change anything.

If I run `ssh -vvv server`, I see that it is offering id_rsa_other.

Comment: On server do you have `authorized_keys` file?

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

Comment: @RomeoNinov. There is no `authorized_keys` file

Answer (score 0):

To make working `ssh` authentication, based on keys you need on target machine (server) to have a file, usually located in user home directory, subdirectory `.ssh` named `authorized_keys` which should contain public keys of public/private keys pairs you want to use. In this case is `id_rsa_other.pub`. So log in to the server and exec these commands:

```
cd ~/.ssh
cat id_rsa_other.pub >authorized_keys
```

And then try to login in to this server using keys